# Is there any way to avoid the use of my app after removed it from the store?

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I need to unpublish my app from the app store and the play store. If I do, people how downloaded the application may continue using it? Can we prevent this?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Also, some sites provide direct apk of the apps. If your app is also listed there, the users can still download and install the app.

Comment: If you are using some kind of API or authentication then all you can do is to break the calls and revoke the authentication so that no one can use it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't have authentication calls.

Comment: Then I don't think there is anything you can do about it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not Google Play's support.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is imposible.

Maybe you can update your app to a hello world app, then people who update it, can't go back.

But you can't un-install its apps and avoids its use.

Comment: I think that possibility, but people could or couldn't update it. :(

Comment: It is the best idea. Most of the phones updates the app automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If your App have some API to hit, return some error message on this.
If your application is for offline use, then what make sense to do this?
Let users use it.